# Nombre de columna ambigua 'RFC | SQL

Tags: sql

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema en sql:

> Nombre de columna ambigua 'RFC'

Y este es mi codigo :

```
SELECT Cliente,RFC,SUBTOTAL,IVA,TOTAL
FROM GSO_Honorarios G
JOIN Contabilidad C
ON G.RFC = C.RFC
```

Intente ponerle un alias al RFC pero auna si me da error

Espero que me puedan ayudar , de antemano gracias

Comment: Cuando realizas un `JOIN`, las tablas G y C, deben representar a las columnas. Por lo que si llamas a `Cliente`, debes especificar si es `G.Cliente` o `C.Cliente`, como lo hiciste en el `ON`, mismo caso para las demas columnas

Comment: @Excorpion eso parece más una respuesta que un comentario.

Comment: Tu hiciste la respuesta, no pasa nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mismo error lo dice, el nombre de la columna es ambiguo. Esto se debe a que la columna existe en ambas tablas. Lo que debes hacer es poner a que tabla pertenece. Eso debe ser una práctica constante cuando uses más de una tabla en una instrucción.

```
SELECT C.Cliente,
       C.RFC,
       G.SUBTOTAL,
       G.IVA,
       G.TOTAL
FROM GSO_Honorarios G
JOIN Contabilidad   C ON G.RFC = C.RFC;
```

Comment: Gracias tu comentario fue mi solucion